# Метод Prepare выдает не существующий адресс

Tags: sql, postgresql, golang

Вот есть небольшой пакет для инициализации запросов к БД postgresql:

```
package postgresql

// Работа с postgresql

import (
"database/sql"
_ "errors"
"fmt"
"log"
"sync"
_ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var db *sql.DB
var Requests dbRequests

type dbRequests struct {
Rlock        *sync.RWMutex
RequestsList map[string]*sql.Stmt
}

func (dbr *dbRequests) initRequests() error {
var err error
dbr.Rlock = &sync.RWMutex{}
dbr.Rlock.Lock()
defer dbr.Rlock.Unlock()
fff := make(map[string]*sql.Stmt)
//  dbr.RequestsList = make(map[string]*sql.Stmt)
fff["asd"], err = db.Prepare("INSERT INTO \"AvtorizationR\" (\"HashUser\", \"HashRole\", \"HashOrg\") VALUES ($1, $2, $3)")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("::::", err)
}
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("sssssss")
    return err
}

  return nil
  }
  func init() {
// Подключение к postgresql
fmt.Println("----------------------------------------")
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5433 user=admin password=Oma524744 dbname=Role sslmode=disable")

    if err != nil {
    log.Panic("Postgresql not found!:", err)
}

if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
    log.Panic("Postgresql not reply!:", err)
}
log.Println("\nPostgresql running!")
fmt.Println("::::::::::::::::::1111111111111111111111111111::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::")
ss, err := db.Prepare("SELECT * FROM \"AvtorizationR\"")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
rows, err := ss.Query()

for rows.Next() {
    fmt.Println("ЕСТЬ МАЗАФАКА")

}

fff := make(map[string]*sql.Stmt)
fff["asd"], err = db.Prepare("INSERT INTO \"AvtorizationR\" (\"HashUser\", \"HashRole\", \"HashOrg\") VALUES ($1, $2, $3)")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("asdasdasdadsasdasdasdasddddddddddddddddd::::", err)
}

//Запуск инициализации запроса
if err = Requests.initRequests(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("::::::::::::::::::", err, "::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::")
}

 }
```

Дак вот программа вылетает на prepare именно если я пишу его в функции initRequests. Выдается сообщение, что я обращаюсь по несуществующему адресу. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А где вы вызываете функцию `init()`, которая должна создать подключение и заполнить переменную `db` ? Или в golang вызовы как то скрыто происходят ...

Comment: Пакет сам вызывает функцию init при инциализации пакета в приложении, в других языках так же есть аналоги данной функции...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спустя несколько часов раздумий я понял в чем проблема, при данном вызове функции Open()

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5433 user=admin password=Oma524744 dbname=Role sslmode=disable")
```

Явно видно только одну новую переменную err. Так как db глобальная думал, что ей просто присвоит значение. Но как оказалось он создавал две новые переменные в данной функции init() и уничтожал ее при выходе. Для того что бы решить данную проблема потребовалось немного изменить код:

```
var err error
db, err = sql.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5433 user=admin password=Oma524744 dbname=Role sslmode=disable")
```

Таким образом новых переменных не обнаружено и применяется операция присваивания. Всем удачной будущей работы с golang!